# Create new ASP.NET Core project that targets .NET Framework by DotNet CLI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I try to create a new ASP.NET Core project that target the classic .NET Framework. The template [web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new#web) and [webapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new#webapi) have the option `framework`, but this don't accept .NET Framework value like :

```
dotnet new web --name MyWebProject --framework net48
```

> Error: Invalid parameter(s):
> --framework net48
> 'net48' is not a valid value for --framework (Framework).

How create ASP.NET Core project that targets .NET Framework from DotNet CLI?

If it isn't possible, do you know a solution to do this in command line?

PS : I know the Visual Studio template `ASP.NET Core empty` let select .NET Framework. I search a solution from command line, preferably with DotNet CLI.

Comment: You **CANNOT** by definition create a **.NET Core** project that targets the "full, classic" .NET Framework (neither from the CLI, nor in Visual Studio). That would no longer be a **.NET Core** project - but instead a "regular" .NET project..... the question is more: **WHY** would you want to do this??

Comment: *I know the Visual Studio template ASP.NET Core empty let select .NET Framework* - that statement is **false** - if you create a new ASP.NET Core (empty) project, you can **only** select the various .NET Core runtimes - any that you have installed - but you **CANNOT** pick the full, classic .NET 4.8 as runtime....

Comment: @marc_s, ASP.NET Core is a web framework in .NET Standard. The runtime choice is just a line in csproj. Yes, the web framework's name can be misleading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this to create ASP.NET Core empty Web App that targets 4.7.1:

```sh
dotnet new web --target-framework-override net471
```

I saw it [there](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1406).
The generated project file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to set .net frameworks with a default template. You can view the framework's options by running: **dotnet new web --help**:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Voada.png)